# Optimization of "def do_GET(self)"

Tags: python, optimization

This code works nicely for my purposes, but I would like to improve it exponentially.

What are some steps I can take?  I'm interested in optimization, refactoring, and clean-code.

```
  def do_GET(self):
    qs = {}
    path = self.path
    print path
    if path.endswith('robots.txt'):
      self.send_response(500)
      self.send_header('Connection', 'close')
      return
    if '?' in path:
      path, tmp = path.split('?', 1)
      qs = urlparse.parse_qs(tmp)
      print path, qs
    if 'youtube' in path:
     ID = qs.get('vID')
     LTV = qs.get('channelID')
     EMAIL = qs.get('uEmail')
     TIME = qs.get('Time')
     userID = qs.get('uID')
     URL = qs.get('contentUrl')
     channelID = str(LTV)[2:-2]
     print channelID
     uEmail = str(EMAIL)[2:-2]
     print uEmail
     ytID = str(ID)[2:-2]
     print ytID
     ytURL = str("https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=%s" % ytID)
     print ytURL
     uTime = str(TIME)[2:-2]
     print uTime
     uID = str(userID)[2:-2]
     print uID
     contentUrl = str(URL)[2:-2]
     print contentUrl
     if sys.platform == "darwin":
      subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
      sleep(1)
      subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
      sleep(1)
      subprocess.Popen('./test.py %s'%ytURL, shell=True)
     elif sys.platform == "linux2":
      subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
      sleep(1)
      subprocess.Popen('./test.py %s'% ytURL, shell=True)
    #subprocess.Popen('chromium-browser https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=%s'% ytID, shell=True)
      sleep(2)
    #subprocess.Popen("./fullscreen", shell=True)
     elif sys.platform == "win32":
      os.system('tskill chrome')
      browser = webbrowser.open('http://youtube.com/watch?v="%s"'% ytID)
      log.warn("'%s':,video request:'%s' @ %s"% (channelID, ytID, time))
    #playyt = subprocess.Popen("/Users/Shared/ltv.ap
```

Comment: Some explanation of its purpose would be helpful. That way we don't accidentally break it. That is the first feedback. Always use [docstring at the beginning of a function explaining its purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format).

Comment: Why are you running ./killtv a bunch of times and then running another python script (test.py) from your python script?

Comment: http get request opens a pyside window (test.py), killtv just closes the previous request/window

Comment: About your os specific code why are you only opening the browser when `sys.platform` is `win32`? If you add certain details about what you are trying to do by `test.py` then the os specific code can be converted into loops based on values stored in dictionaries with key being `sys.platform`.

Comment: @AseemBansal can you elaborate... I think this is something i'm searching for. test.py opens up a pyside window with a url passed in from the get request.

Comment: @sirvonandrethomas I updated my answer to add details regarding the os-specific code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using

```
IS, LTV, EMAIL, TIME, userID, URL  = map(\
    qs.get, ['vID', 'channelID', 'uEmail', 'Time', 'uID', 'contentUrl'])

channelID, uEmail, ytID, uTime, uID, contentUrl = map(\
    lambda x : str(x)[2:-2], [LTV, EMAIL, ID, TIME, userID, URL])

for i in (channelID, uEmail, ytID, uTime, uID, contentUrl):
    print i

ytURL = str("https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=%s" % ytID)
print ytURL
```

instead of

```
ID = qs.get('vID')
LTV = qs.get('channelID')
EMAIL = qs.get('uEmail')
TIME = qs.get('Time')
userID = qs.get('uID')
URL = qs.get('contentUrl')
channelID = str(LTV)[2:-2]
print channelID
uEmail = str(EMAIL)[2:-2]
print uEmail
ytID = str(ID)[2:-2]
print ytID
ytURL = str("https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=%s" % ytID)
print ytURL
uTime = str(TIME)[2:-2]
print uTime
uID = str(userID)[2:-2]
print uID
contentUrl = str(URL)[2:-2]
print contentUrl
```

The first one just prints `ytURL` at the end but it can be changed easily if you really want. Other than that they do the same thing. But I am sure the first one is much easier to modify and maintain.

Other than that I can only say after I know what this program is about.

It might also be a good idea to keep os-specific functions(like you are doing after checking for the os) into separate functions. It would make maintaining and modifying the code much easier.

You should also read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), particularly the part about code-layout. Your indentation is not good.

What I meant was that this can be converted into

```
if sys.platform == "darwin":
      subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
      sleep(1)
      subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
      sleep(1)
      subprocess.Popen('./test.py %s'%ytURL, shell=True)
elif sys.platform == "linux2":
      subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
      sleep(1)
      subprocess.Popen('./test.py %s'% ytURL, shell=True)
```

this equivalent structure

```
OS_DETAIL = { 'darwin' : 2, 'linux2' : 1}
for i in xrange(OS_DETAIL[sys.platform]):
    subprocess.Popen('./killltv', shell=True)
    sleep(1)
else:
    subprocess.Popen('./test.py %s'% ytURL, shell=True)
```

It doesn't solve the complete problem because I am not sure whether you'll need those commented statements or not. If the `sleep(2)` is actually needed in case of `linux2` then you can store a tuple in the `OS_DETAILS` dictionary. But the problem with this approach is your `win32` part. It is totally different. It can be taken care of using an structure like this.

```
if sys.platform in ['darwin', 'linux2`]:
    #place the code I have just suggested for these 2 
elif sys.platform == "win32"
    #place your code for win32
```

But as you can see this isn't the best way. It is better than the current solution but if the code for `win32` can be refactored in some way (I don't know its functionality so don't ask) to fit the same pattern then it all comes down to a simple dictionary and a loop structure.

Answer (score 4):

Some notes about your code:

- Use 4 spaces for indentation.
- Local variables should use the underscore style: `name_of_variable`.
- This function is too long. Split code in functions.
- When writing conditionals, try to keep a `if`/`elif`/`else` layout, without early returns, you'll see that readability is greatly enhanced.
- Use dictionaries to hold multiple named values, not one variable per value, that's too messy.
- Some patterns are repeated all over the place, abstract them.
- Don't update variables in-place unless there is a good reason for it (99% of the time there isn't).

I'd write (`show_video` has been left out, it's clearly another function's task):

```
def do_GET(self):
    url = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
    if 'youtube' not in url.path:
        sys.stderr.write("Not a youtube path: {0}".format(self.path))
    elif url.path == '/robots.txt':
        self.send_response(500)
        self.send_header('Connection', 'close')
    else:
        url_params = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query)
        keys = ["vID", "channelID", "uEmail", "Time", "uID", "contentUrl"]
        params = dict((key, url_params[key][2:-2]) for key in keys)
        yt_url = "https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v={0}".format(params["vID"])
        show_video(yt_url)
```